# Turn an IO[List[String]] in scala to a String that's comma separated

Tags: list, scala, io

I have a `IO[List[String]]` (of urls string) that I'd like to convert into a comma separated String. Is there a join or something I can use? I'm getting caught up on the `IO` type.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `map` method to apply a function to the result of the `IO` action:

```scala
def toCommaSeparated(
  io: IO[List[String]]
): IO[String] =
  io.map(_.mkString(", "))
```

Comment: Thanks. So with IO, is there no way to get an input of `IO[List[String]]` and output a `String`? It always has to be wrapped with `IO[String]`?

Comment: As Alin pointed out, there are ways to get the String out. But it's almost always a bad idea as it destroys referential transparency, which is the point of using `IO` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. You could use `unsafeRunSync()` or `unsafePerformIO()` once at the end to evaluate the encapsulated code.

But I advise against it, because [IO](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/2.x/datatypes/io)'s purpose is to encapsulate side-effecting code in the first place, that would otherwise make code impure, to be wrapped inside the IO and unable to evaluate unless and until we want it to do so.

In a monadic way you write code using the `map` and `flatMap` functions to compose other functions and ideally call one of these unsafe operations only once, at the end. Getting the value out of a monadic context is contrary to it's purpose in the first place, and usually hints a code smell in your design.

A more logical approach would be to use a [Comonad](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/comonad.html), which has an `extract` method that instead takes an `F[A]` and extracts the `A`. You must be sure you can get an `A` from an `F[A]` when calling it though (e.g. you cannot get an `A` from a `List[A]` if the list is empty).